# КАК ПРИСВОИТЬ картинку PictureBox чему нибудь в программе C#

Tags: c#, picturebox

На форме есть Picture box  ... Мне нужно взять с него картинку и запихнуть в какую нибудь переменную или экземпляр класса или что нибудь ещё. И спустя некоторое время присвоить pictureBox значение этой переменной, грубо говоря вернуть картинку назад... Сразу говорю сохранять мне в файле НЕ нужно, как мне постоянно тычет гугл. Что делать ? SOS! Работую в Vs 2017.

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Bitmap Bs;
    public Graphics Zz;    
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        Bs = new Bitmap( pictureBox1.Width, pictureBox1.Height);
        Zz= Graphics.FromImage(Bs);

        Zz.Clear(Color.Red);
        pictureBox1.Image = Bs;
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Image im = pictureBox1.Image;

        Zz.Clear(Color.White);

        pictureBox1.Image = im;
    }
}
```

Comment: Ну и сохраняйте в переменную. В чем проблема-то?

Comment: Alexander Petrov; В том то и проблемма , что не присваивает. Не в Bitmap, не в image. Присваивало бы - не спрашивал бы

Comment: Покажите свой код, как пытаетесь присвоить.

Comment: Залил код в свой же вопрос. Но это лишь тестовый вариант.  После нажатия кнопки PictureBox должен окраситься белым, но вернуть красную заливку, а он остается белым.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Не понял вот это:

> PictureBox должен окраситься белым, но вернуть красную заливку

```
private static Image im;
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    im = pictureBox1.Image.Clone();
    ...
```

Comment: Уже не важно, твой код работает) Большое спасибо)   Можно и без Static ))  И почему мой вариант с простым присваиванием не хотел работать, а вариант с Clone() заработал?

Comment: @Shadow Видимо, потому, что `Clone` создает новый объект - копию изобажения в момент вызова `Clone`, а присваивание копирует ссылку на тот же самый `Image`. На здоровье. Успехов!

Comment: Ещё раз спасибо за ответ) Благодаря тебе, этой ночью Я буду спать))

Comment: @Shadow Очень рад. Спокойного сна и приятных сновидений ).